# Github no me reconoce la ruta de las img

Tags: javascript, github-pages

https://github.com/ayelenleclerc/aluraLatam-challenger-juego-del-ahorcado

Hola, tengo un problema, github pages, me tira el error
img0.png:1
GET https://ayelenleclerc.github.io/img/ahorcado/img0.png 404 (Not Found)

pero en el repositorio está, intente poniendo la ruta con ../img/ahorcado/img0.png, con ./img/ahorcado/img0.png directamente con img/ahoracado/img0.png

me sigue tirando el mismo error, ya se no se como hacerlo, en la pc me funciona bien, si descargo el repositorio y lo ejecuto desde otra pc, funciona bien.
lei todas las respuestas relacionadas, y aplique todas las soluciones dadas a esas respuestas. y nada.

En que me estoy equivocando?
gracias

Comment: Necesitas poner el nombre del repo después de `ayelenleclerc.github.io`. Por ejemplo: GET [`https://ayelenleclerc.github.io/aluraLatam-challenger-juego-del-ahorcado/img/ahorcado/img0.png`](https://ayelenleclerc.github.io/aluraLatam-challenger-juego-del-ahorcado/img/ahorcado/img0.png)

Comment: Jaime gracias por tu respuesta, lo que puse fue el link del repositorio para que puedan ver el codigo. y si me podian decir porque cuando esta activa la page no reconoce las rutas. :)

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo! gracias! era un ruta equivocada

Comment: Me alegra lo solucionaras. Considera agregar una respuesta explicando cómo solucionaste el problema. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Solucione el problema cambiando todas las rutas. El problema estaba en que llamaba como en la pc con ../, lo había cambiado a img/img0.png, pero no en todos lados, porque no lo veia, ahora cambie todas sin / y funciona lo mas bien!
https://ayelenleclerc.github.io/aluraLatam-challenger-juego-del-ahorcado/
ahora si pueden jugar!
muchas gracias!!!!!